# Extract phone numbers from email-signature (regex)

Tags: python, regex, phone-number

I'm trying to parse an email signature, that can contain multiple phone numbers in different formats. I've managed to come up with this Regex:

```
(?<![%_])\b(\+?\d{1,}[\s.-]?\(?\d{1,}\)?[\s.-]?\(?\d{1,}\)?[\s.-]?\d{1,}[\s.-]?\d{1,}[\s.-]?\d{3,})
```

This matches almost any phone number. (The reason there are many digits classes is because the number can arrive like this: `+86 21 3387 6 532`). I need two things though.

1.I don't know how to force the match to come from the same line. For example:

```
Newtown Square, PA 19073
360.751.1471 Some Other Text Here
```

The regex matches `19073 360.751.1471` instead of `360.751.1471`.

2.The are different types of numbers, and I want to catch each type with a different regex. I.E. Cell, Fax, Office, Mobile ETC.. Lets focus on `Mobile`. It can come in different formats each time like the following (I want to catch them all with the same regex):

```
M: 360.123.1471
M 360.123.1471
(M): 360.123.1471
(M):360.123.1471
M:360.123.1471
```

Every prefixcan be either lower or upper case.

The reason I need to capture them by the prefix, is because I get signatures such as this:

```
Jane Doe
Ocean Export Agent
Some Company, Inc.
Celebrating 100 years!
p:
410-123-3 123  m: 410-123-1234
a:
111 Cromwell Park Drive, Glen Burnie, MD 21061
w:
website.com   e: janedoe@somecompany.com
```

And I want to capture the mobile number out of it.

How can I change my regex to solve both cases?

Comment: `formats like the following` ... are these _all_ the possible formats?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've updated the question and now it has every format I'm interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RegEx is catching the newline as a whitespace character. You can swap it out instead for the literal 'space' character, which won't match a newline.

Here's how it looks like fixed (replaced `\s` with  , and wrapped it with the above start/end of line matching):

```
(?<![%_])\b(\+?\d{1,}[ .-]?\(?\d{1,}\)?[ .-]?\(?\d{1,}\)?[ .-]?\d{1,}[ .-]?\d{1,}[ .-]?\d{3,})
```

[Watch it in action here.](https://regex101.com/r/HNhrWl/2)

Comment: Thanks. This solved 1 for me. But for 2, the problem is that I have multiple phone types, and a line(or multiple lines) could be like the following: `O: 111.111.1111 M: 111.111.1112 F: 111.111.1113`. This is why I asked specifically to match the numbers with the prefixes before them (You can ignore the postfixes)

Comment: Oops, guess I misunderstood. I fixed/edited my answer, hope this helped :)

Comment: It did for 1. Still didn't solve 2 :). I edited the question with an example of a signature

Comment: [It's still matching both numbers though?](https://regex101.com/r/c5kGtz/1)

Comment: Yea it still matches all of the numbers, which is great. But now I'd like to be more specific. To catch only the one(and there should only be 1 per signature) with `M:/M /(M): ... ETC` before it

Comment: My mission is to extract the mobile number, fax number, office number or w/e from an email signature. Maybe it will help clarify what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

When the regex gets too complex, because it tries to match to many cases, then often support by an algorithmic approach is needed.

Here the phone-number in different formats (using dot or dash as separator) might be good candidate for a regex.

But when adding the markers (in variations like prefix and suffix or upper-case and lower-case) the regex is getting more and more complex.

Also the line-breaks in a multi-line text might be hard for a regex to cover.

## Use the markers for location, the regex for extraction

When we scan a text for phone-numbers, we can use *markers* (like in your case) to locate them first. Then in the next step we could parse the phone-number using a regex. The phone-number may be located before or after the *marker* if the marker is used as prefix or suffix respectively.

See following approach:

1. a set of *marker* strings used to narrow down the location
2. a regex for the phone-number to extract it

```py
import re

text = '''M: 360.751.0001
M 360.751.0002
(M): 360.751.0003
(M):360.751.0004
M:360.751.0005
(Mobile): 360.751.0006
(Mobile):360.751.0007
(Mobile) 360.751.0008
Mobile: 360.751.0009
Mobile:360.751.0010
Mobile 360.751.0011
360.751.0012 Mobile
360.751.0013 (M)
360.751.0014 M'''

email_signature = '''
Jane Doe
Ocean Export Agent
Some Company, Inc.
Celebrating 100 years!
p:
410-123-3 001  m: 410-123-0002
a:
111 Cromwell Park Drive, Glen Burnie, MD 21061
w:
website.com   e: janedoe@somecompany.com
'''

# leading space for a suffix, trailing space for a prefix
phone_markers = {' M', 'M ', 'M:', '(M)', ' Mobile', 'Mobile ', 'Mobile:', '(Mobile)'}

def find_phone_numbers_marked(text, phone_markers):
    phone_numbers = []
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        found_marked = [(marker, line.find(marker)) for marker in 
phone_markers if line.find(marker) >= 0]
        for marker, position in found_marked:
            if marker.startswith(' '): 
                text_marked = line[:position]  # text before marker
            else:
                text_marked = line[position:]  # text after marker
            found_numbers = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,4}', text_marked)
            print(line, f"Marker '{marker}' at position {position}, found number:", found_numbers)
            phone_numbers.extend(found_numbers)
    return phone_numbers
 

total_lines = len(text.split('\n'))
print(f"== Searching in {total_lines} lines ..")
result = find_phone_numbers_marked(text, phone_markers)
print(f"== Found {len(result)} numbers:", result)

total_lines = len(email_signature.split('\n'))
print(f"== Searching in {total_lines} lines ..")
phone_markers.update([m.lower() for m in phone_markers])  # also include lowercase version of markers
result = find_phone_numbers_marked(email_signature, phone_markers)
print("== Found:", result)
```

Output:

```
== Searching in 14 lines ..
M: 360.751.0001 Marker 'M:' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0001']
M 360.751.0002 Marker 'M ' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0002']
(M): 360.751.0003 Marker '(M)' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0003']
(M):360.751.0004 Marker '(M)' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0004']
M:360.751.0005 Marker 'M:' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0005']
(Mobile): 360.751.0006 Marker '(Mobile)' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0006']
(Mobile):360.751.0007 Marker '(Mobile)' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0007']
(Mobile) 360.751.0008 Marker '(Mobile)' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0008']
Mobile: 360.751.0009 Marker 'Mobile:' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0009']
Mobile:360.751.0010 Marker 'Mobile:' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0010']
Mobile 360.751.0011 Marker 'Mobile ' at position 0, found number: ['360.751.0011']
360.751.0012 Mobile Marker ' Mobile' at position 12, found number: ['360.751.0012']
360.751.0012 Mobile Marker ' M' at position 12, found number: ['360.751.0012']
360.751.0013 (M) Marker '(M)' at position 13, found number: []
360.751.0014 M Marker ' M' at position 12, found number: ['360.751.0014']
== Found 14 numbers: ['360.751.0001', '360.751.0002', '360.751.0003', '360.751.0004', '360.751.0005', '360.751.0006', '360.751.0007', '360.751.0008', '360.751.0009', '360.751.0010', '360.751.0011', '360.751.0012', '360.751.0012', '360.751.0014']
== Searching in 12 lines ..
410-123-3 001  m: 410-123-0002 Marker 'm:' at position 15, found number: ['410-123-0002']
410-123-3 001  m: 410-123-0002 Marker ' m' at position 14, found number: ['410-123-3']
111 Cromwell Park Drive, Glen Burnie, MD 21061 Marker ' M' at position 37, found number: []
website.com   e: janedoe@somecompany.com Marker 'm ' at position 10, found number: []
== Found: ['410-123-0002', '410-123-3']
```

Not yet perfect, but could be refined in markers and regex.